# How to migrate from chef-11.10 to chef-12 on AWS Ops-Work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, devops

Right now I have a couple of web-server instance(apache) are running chef-11.10 stack and we want to migrate the instances to chef-12 stack with minimal downtime if required?

Basically, I am looking for best practices which can be followed to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

I've never migrated from Chef 11 to Chef 12; instead, what I do is "move" to Chef 12.

The tool I use to do this is [`knife backup`](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup): `knife backup export roles environments clients users nodes data bags -D .`

Install Chef 12 and then attempt to push your backup to Chef 12 (you will need to make sure that you've updated `knife.rb` to new server): `knife backup restore roles environments clients users nodes data bags -D .`

Fix any errors you run into (hopefully none); then, use DNS to switch the clients from Chef 11 server to Chef 12 server; hopefully you use DNS for the chef server; as the change/upgrade is trivial.